# CakePHP 3 : Modifying Find Data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I currently have in CakePHP 3 a table called Tickets that has a few flags such as head_ticket and latest_ticket. Essentially when ever I edit a record I create a new row (a uuid field keeps the records linked together) and set the latest_ticket flag to true as this row contains the latest information.

What I would like to know is that is there a way I can do something in the find where I can get all the records that have the head_ticket set to true but update the head ticket data columns returned on-the-fly with the latest data from the row that has the latest_ticket flag set to true at the same time? It's almost like an afterFind scenario but one which has been deprecated in CakePHP 3

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [the migration guide](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/orm-migration.html#no-afterfind-event-or-virtual-fields), it contains the answer to your question and probably more things you want and should to know when coming from 2.x:

> Using the [Modifying Results with Map/Reduce](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#map-reduce) features of the ORM allow you to build aggregated data from your results, which is another use case that the afterFind callback was often used for.

The documentation about Map/Reduce contains an example for result set aggregation based on some filter, I think this is pretty much what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll investigate further.